# What is a structured note and when does it make sense as part of my financial plan?

Tags: investing, retirement

I have been talking to retirement planners recently and more than one has suggested that structured notes as part of my strategy for investing after retirement. I thought I was pretty financially savvy, but I am completely unfamiliar with this instrument.

I'm always a little skeptical when financial planners line up to promote a specific type of investment (see also annuities), so I wanted an impartial perspective on what this type of investment is about and when it might make sense in the portfolio for someone who has recently retired.

Comment: Did you start with Google? It’s first non-ad link is https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/structurednote.asp

Comment: I guess since Google exists we can shut down this site since it is no longer needed.  Shut it down boys!

Comment: The first topic in https://money.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask is "Search and research".  If you did either, it's not apparent from the question.